# call to another function in a dll causes access violation

Tags: c++, dll, access-violation, disassembly

okay so I'm starting to realize that dll arn't the simplest of things to understand, I'm trying to make a dll which is VC6 compatible, I got some code working in VS2010 but in trying to work out how to get that code to work for a VC6 project I've found the following issue:

My call to the dll looks like this

```
MyDll::connect();
```

when i try and run a program which uses this function, it starts out fine but as soon as it gets to a function call i.e.

```
VOID connect()
{
hello();    //0xC0000005: access violation
}

VOID hello()
{
    int i = 1;
}
```

the disassembly looks like this:

```
->  00000000   ???
    00000001   ???
    00000002   ???
    00000003   ???
    00000004   ???
    00000005   ???
    00000006   ???
    00000007   ???
    00000008   ???
    00000009   ???
    etc...
```

Comment: Build debug versions of both the DLL and the program using the DLL, and run in a debugger.

Comment: Both are built in debug not sure what you mean by run in a debugger exactly other than the debug you get when it falls over...

Comment: Are you building a DLL in one version of VC++ and then calling it from a programme written in another version?  I think that's what I've understood.  The problem is likely to be that they are using different versions of the Visual C++ Runtime.

Comment: Nope they are both VC6, I had originally started writing the dll in VS2010 but in my quest to track down the access violation, I wrote it in VC6 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't exported the function .....a program is not permitted to access a function in a dll unless that function is registered as exported function.
to do that you should prototype it like this

to export a function inside a class this function should
1- be public member.
2- be a static member

```
class MyDll{
   public:
   static void connect();
}
//then redeclare it like this
#ifdef _cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif
__declspec(dllexport) void  MyDll::connect(){
//TODO
}
#ifdef _cplusplus
}
#endif
```

do this for any class member function you want to export

this is an example

[Creating a simple Dynamic Link Library example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682507(v=vs.85).aspx)